# Trying to add Textboxes to a userform dynamically?

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I have code inside a excel workbook that helps me create mass emails to send to users of various programs. I have a userform that pops up and the user populates all the info needed. but that only counts for one app at a time. Can someone share code with me that dynamically adds textboxes to a userform dependant on what checkboxes are ticked ?

In the first frame I have check boxes that indicate what applications are affected, second frame I have option buttons to describe what type of incident and then I would like the textboxes to appear according to what has been ticked.

Any guidance much appreciated as I think this is way too deep for me at the moment

I've reverse engineered this code it adds the boxes I want but I need to be able to populate them with cell data and then use it in the emails:

```
Option Explicit

Dim SpnColct As Collection

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim cSpnEvnt As cControlEvent
    Dim ctlSB As Control
    Dim ctlTXT As Control
    Dim lngCounter As Long

    For lngCounter = 1 To 7
        Set ctlTXT = Me.Frame7.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "Text" & lngCounter)
        ctlTXT.Name = "Text" & lngCounter
        ctlTXT.Left = 5
        ctlTXT.Height = 125: ctlTXT.Width = 280
        ctlTXT.Top = (lngCounter - 1) * 125 + 2

        Set cSpnEvnt = New cControlEvent
        Set cSpnEvnt.SP = ctlSB
        Set cSpnEvnt.TXT = ctlTXT
        SpnColct.Add cSpnEvnt

    Next lngCounter

    Me.Frame1.ScrollHeight = (lngCounter - 1) * 17 + 2

End Sub
```

This added to a class module:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents SP As MSForms.SpinButton
Public WithEvents TXT As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub SP_SpinDown()
    SP.Value = SP.Value - 1
    MsgBox "Spin Down to " & SP.Value
End Sub

Private Sub SP_SpinUp()
    SP.Value = SP.Value + 1
    MsgBox "Spin Up to " & SP.Value
End Sub

Private Sub TXT_Change()
    MsgBox "You changed the value."
End Sub
```

[image: Userform]

Comment: Wouldn't you rather have all textboxes present but disabled/enabled upon which checkbox is ticked? If you think you are in this way too deep, don't make it hard on yourself :)

Comment: at the moment it is 7 applications and the list could get bigger, I currently do have 7 textboxes but would hate to think how to add another one as the code is so messy

Comment: If the code is so messy, I suggest by tackling that first before you add any additional code/mechanics. It's a nightmare to come back to messy code after a while.

Comment: deleted it to start again, won't let it beat me. found some code that I can adjust to dynamically add textboxes. just need to work out how to read the text from the boxes now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated** This is going to be a bit of a long one - step through it see if you understand it. Have changed it to create the textboxes on the CheckBox_Click event but change to the commandbutton if you wish. Any more then this and I think you'll need to start a new question.

I've been doing something similar recently and found that the reason you're having issues is due to the order of loading objects. I unfortunately can't find the link that explains it at the moment (will update if can) but briefly to be able to achieve this you need an additional `Class` that does the loading of the objects, otherwise the `Userform` can't see them. This is the kind of solution that I came up with (using your example)

**Userform:**

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents cControls As EventController

Private Sub cControls_Click(ctrl As CheckBoxControl)
    Dim tBox As TextBoxControl
    Dim i As Long
    Dim NextTop As Long, FrameHeight As Long

    For i = 1 To cControls.GetControls.Count
        Debug.Print TypeName(cControls.GetControl(i))
        If TypeName(cControls.GetControl(i)) = "TextBoxControl" Then
            Set tBox = cControls.GetControl(i)
            If tBox.TXT.Parent Is Me.Frame7 Then
                NextTop = tBox.Top + tBox.Height
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    Set tBox = cControls.AddTextBox
    With tBox
        .Height = 125
        .Width = 280
        .Left = 5
        .Top = NextTop
        .TXT.Text = ctrl.cBox.Caption
        FrameHeight = NextTop + .Height
    End With
    If FrameHeight > Me.Frame7.InsideHeight Then
        With Me.Frame7
            .ScrollBars = fmScrollBarsVertical
            .ScrollHeight = FrameHeight
            .Scroll yAction:=6
        End With
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cBox As CheckBoxControl
    Set cControls = New EventController
    ' This can be set to a userform or a frame
    Set cControls.UserForm = Me
    For i = 1 To 8
        Set cBox = cControls.AddCheckBox
        cBox.cBox.Left = 5
        With cBox.cBox
            .Top = 5 + (i - 1) * .Height
            .Caption = IIf(i = 8, "App Unknown", "App " & i)
        End With
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub cControls_Change(ctrl As TextBoxControl)
    ' This can be handled in the class instead as you were - just doing it in the userform to show the exposing of the event
    MsgBox ctrl.TXT.Name & " Change"
End Sub

Private Sub cControls_SpinDown(ctrl As TextBoxControl)
    ' This can be handled in the class instead as you were - just doing it in the userform to show the exposing of the event
    With ctrl.SP
        If .Value >0 Then
            .Value = .Value - 1
        End If
    End With
    MsgBox ctrl.SP.Name & " Spin Down"
End Sub

Private Sub cControls_SpinUp(ctrl As TextBoxControl)
' This can be handled in the class instead as you were - just doing it in the userform to show the exposing of the event
    With ctrl.SP
        .Value = .Value + 1
    End With
    MsgBox ctrl.SP.Name & " Spin Up"

End Sub
```

**Classes** - These need to be named as in bold

**EventControl**

```
Option Explicit

Private CtrlCollection As Collection
Private cUserForm As UserForm1

Public Event SpinDown(ctrl As TextBoxControl)
Public Event SpinUp(ctrl As TextBoxControl)
Public Event Change(ctrl As TextBoxControl)
Public Event Click(ctrl As CheckBoxControl)
Public Property Set UserForm(v As UserForm1)
    Set cUserForm = v
End Property
Public Property Get UserForm() As UserForm1
    Set UserForm = cUserForm
End Property
Public Function AddTextBox() As TextBoxControl
    Dim tBox As TextBoxControl
    Set tBox = New TextBoxControl

    tBox.Initialize Me

    CtrlCollection.Add tBox

    Set AddTextBox = tBox

End Function
Public Function AddCheckBox() As CheckBoxControl
    Dim cBox As New CheckBoxControl
    cBox.Initalize Me
    CtrlCollection.Add cBox

    Set AddCheckBox = cBox
End Function
Public Function GetControl(Index As Long)
    Set GetControl = CtrlCollection(Index)
End Function
Public Function GetControls() As Collection
    Set GetControls = CtrlCollection
End Function
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set CtrlCollection = New Collection
End Sub
Public Sub SpinDown(ctrl As TextBoxControl)
    RaiseEvent SpinDown(ctrl)
End Sub
Public Sub SpinUp(ctrl As TextBoxControl)
    RaiseEvent SpinUp(ctrl)
End Sub
Public Sub Change(ctrl As TextBoxControl)
    RaiseEvent Change(ctrl)
End Sub
Public Sub Click(ctrl As CheckBoxControl)
    RaiseEvent Click(ctrl)
End Sub
```

**CheckBoxControl**

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents cBox As MSForms.CheckBox
Private cParent As EventController
Public Property Set Parent(v As EventController)
    Set cParent = v
End Property
Public Property Get Parent() As EventController
    Set Parent = cParent
End Property
Public Sub Initalize(Parent As EventController)
    Set Me.Parent = Parent
    Set cBox = Parent.UserForm.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1")
End Sub

Private Sub cBox_Click()
    Parent.Click Me
End Sub
```

**TextBoxControl**

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents SP As MSForms.SpinButton
Public WithEvents TXT As MSForms.TextBox
Private cParent As EventController
Public Sub Initialize(Parent As EventController)
    Set Me.Parent = Parent
    With Parent.UserForm.Frame7.Controls
        Set SP = .Add("Forms.SpinButton.1")
        Set TXT = .Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
    End With
End Sub
Public Property Set Parent(v As EventController)
    Set cParent = v
End Property
Public Property Get Parent() As EventController
    Set Parent = cParent
End Property
Public Property Let Left(v As Single)
    TXT.Left = v
    SP.Left = TXT.Left + TXT.Width
End Property
Public Property Get Left() As Single
    Left = TXT.Left
End Property
Public Property Let Top(v As Single)
    TXT.Top = v
    SP.Top = v
End Property
Public Property Get Top() As Single
    Top = TXT.Top
End Property
Public Property Let Height(v As Single)
    TXT.Height = v
    SP.Height = v
End Property
Public Property Get Height() As Single
    Height = TXT.Height
End Property
Public Property Let Width(v As Single)
    TXT.Width = v - SP.Width
    SP.Left = TXT.Left + TXT.Width
End Property
Public Property Get Width() As Single
    Width = TXT.Width + SP.Width
End Property

Public Sub SP_SpinDown()
    Parent.SpinDown Me
'    SP.Value = SP.Value - 1
'    MsgBox "Spin Down to " & SP.Value
End Sub
' The commented out lines below you can either leave in here, or handle in the Userform
Public Sub SP_SpinUp()
    Parent.SpinUp Me
'    SP.Value = SP.Value + 1
'    MsgBox "Spin Up to " & SP.Value
End Sub

Public Sub TXT_Change()
    Parent.Change Me
'    MsgBox "You changed the value."
End Sub
```

The issue is stemmed from that when the `Userform` is loaded the controls aren't loaded and therefore the `Userform` hasn't registered that they're something that has an `Event`. By using the intermediary class the `Userform` recognises that that class has an `Event` and we load this statically on initialize of the `Userform`. We can then add in whatever `Controls` we want to this `Class` and the `Userform` will handle them.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: that is fantastic for that part of the code. thank you for your help. it's part of a bigger aim. I would like to be able to tick 1 or many in the first frame and then with next lot of option buttons ticked i would like it then to create the textboxes and populate them according to what has been selected. Hoping i'm making sense

Comment: I have also added a picture to try and help explain what i'm trying to achive

Comment: Cheers @tom it’s nearly where I want to get it. I’m currently on holiday so wanted to say cheers for your effort. I now need to adjust your code so that it fills in the text according to what has been ticked on the email type. But I’ll have a go at that first before I seek further help.

Comment: back from holiday now and i'm determined to finish this now. I have run through the code several times to try and understand what is happening. I see in the code that the textboxes are filled before selecting any option buttons. would I need to expand the code to prepare for the 5 possible email outcomes ?