# Check more than one Frame for controls on a userform

Tags: excel, vba, user-controls, userform

I currently have a code that creates text boxes dynamically on a userform back story is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216925/trying-to-add-textboxes-to-a-userform-dynamically).

In the code it checks a single frame on the form for controls and if any are ticked then it runs this code:

```
Function Addcheckboxes(emailtype)
Dim Ctrl As Control
Dim cont As Control
Dim i As Long
Dim h As Long
Dim intAppCount As Integer
Dim result As Long

' Loop through all the applications that have been selected with the email type and then create the appropriate email template on the userform lower box
If SpnColct.Count > 0 Then removeDynamicControls

For Each Ctrl In Me.Frame4.Controls
    If TypeOf Ctrl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
        If Ctrl = True Then
            Call AddTextBox(Mid(Ctrl.Name, 4), emailtype)
            intAppCount = intAppCount + 1
        End If
    
    End If

Next

If intAppCount > 1 Then Me.Frame3.Caption = "Email Templates"

End Function
```

How do I expand this to make it check both Frame 4 and Frame 5 on the userform ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through each frame as follows...

```
Dim Frm As Variant

For Each Frm In Array(Me.Frame4, Me.Frame5)
    For Each Ctrl In Frm.Controls
        If TypeOf Ctrl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            If Ctrl = True Then
                Call AddTextbox(Mid(Ctrl.Name, 4), emailtype)
                intAppCount = intAppCount + 1
            End If
        
        End If
    Next
Next Frm
```

Comment: it's asking for an object in the "for Each Frm In Array(me.frame4, me.frame5)"

Comment: Actually, Frm should be declared as Variant.  See my edited posted.

Comment: ... and Ctrl should be declared `As MSForms.Control` :-;

Comment: all sorted thank you both